# ViewPager not drawing later fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

I am using a ViewPager to create a UI where the user swipes between pages of grid like cells, each containing a news story. The first page is a 'Header' fragment, it has one much larger cell for the featured story. The rest are 'Standard' fragments and have 12 uniform cells in them. The ViewPager lives in my TabletFragment class (this ui is only for tablets, phones use a standard list view), and the only element in that fragment's layout is the ViewPager itself. For fragments loaded into the ViewPager, it can be a 'header' or 'standard' fragment as stated above. TabletFragment calls upon Volley to populate a ListArray with news items from a json feed, then it sends that list along to the child fragments (header and standard). TabletFragment keeps a list of fragments in the viewPager, and if notifyDataSetChanged is called on the adapter, it then calls a method called loadFragments in all the fragments, so they'll actually load the cells in and draw them to the screen. This is called by the volley response when it is through parsing through it. This model seems correct in my head, and it works for the Header fragment and the FIRST Standard fragment. They draw just like I would expect them to. All subsequent Standard fragments, however, just display blank. The news items aren't inserted to the FrameLayouts properly. Before some earlier tinkering, it seemed that all the cells were actually being drawn over top of one another in the first Standard fragment. Changing 'add' to 'replace' fixed that, but I still don't understand why those views were being used when there are other created pages they should be registered to? I will include as much code as I can below to help make what I'm describing more clear, if there are additional files or methods you would like to see point them out and I'll include them in an update. Any guidance on where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated, it seems each fragment should be drawing in their own individual cells but this unfortunately isn't the case at the moment.

**TabletFragment**

```
public class PrestoTabletFragment extends Fragment {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private static PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
private String feedUrl;
private ArrayList<PrestoItem> itemList;
private ArrayList<PrestoTabletContainerFragment> fragmentList;

public static PagerAdapter getAdapter() {
    return pagerAdapter;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRetainInstance(true);

    itemList = new ArrayList<PrestoItem>();
    fragmentList = new ArrayList<PrestoTabletContainerFragment>();
    feedUrl = getArguments().getString("feedUrl");
    PrestoLoader.prestoTabletRequest(getActivity(), feedUrl, itemList);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_presto_tablet_pager, container, false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.presto_tablet_pager);
    pagerAdapter = new DollyTabletPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            fragmentList.get(i).loadFragments();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

private class DollyTabletPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public DollyTabletPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment;

        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("feedUrl", feedUrl);
        data.putParcelableArrayList("itemList", itemList);
        switch (i) {
            case 0: fragment = new PrestoTabletHeaderFragment();
                break;
            default: fragment = new PrestoTabletStandardFragment();
                data.putInt("currentPageIndex", i);
                break;
        }

        fragment.setArguments(data);
        fragmentList.add(i, (PrestoTabletContainerFragment) fragment);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int pageCount;
        int itemCount = itemList.size();
        if (itemCount < 8) {
            pageCount = 1;
        }
        else {
            pageCount = 1 + (itemCount - 7) / 12;
            if ((itemCount - 7) % 12 != 0) {
                pageCount++;
            }
        }

        return pageCount;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();

        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(getCount());

        for (int i = 0; i < fragmentList.size(); i++) {
            PrestoTabletContainerFragment currentFragment = fragmentList.get(i);
                currentFragment.loadFragments();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**TabletRequest**

```
public static void prestoTabletRequest(Context context, String feedUrl, final ArrayList<PrestoItem> itemList) {
    itemList.clear();
    VolleySingleton volley = VolleySingleton.getInstance(context);
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, feedUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray content = response.getJSONObject("modules").getJSONObject("Items").getJSONArray("content");
                for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject currentObject = content.getJSONObject(i);
                    String type = currentObject.getString("type");
                    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("text") || type.equalsIgnoreCase("promo")) {
                        PrestoItem item = new PrestoItem(currentObject);

                        itemList.add(item);


                    }
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            PrestoTabletFragment.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    volley.addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

**StandardFragment**

```
public class PrestoTabletStandardFragment extends Fragment implements PrestoTabletContainerFragment {
private ArrayList<PrestoItem> itemList;
private ArrayList<View> viewList;
private int currentPageIndex;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    currentPageIndex = getArguments().getInt("currentPageIndex");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_presto_tablet_standard, container, false);
    itemList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("itemList");
    viewList = new ArrayList<View>();

    viewList.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.cell_zero_tablet_standard));
    viewList.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.cell_one_tablet_standard));
    viewList.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.cell_two_tablet_standard));
    viewList.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.cell_three_tablet_standard));
    viewList.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.cell_four_tablet_standard));
    viewList.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.cell_five_tablet_standard));
    viewList.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.cell_six_tablet_standard));
    viewList.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.cell_seven_tablet_standard));
    viewList.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.cell_eight_tablet_standard));
    viewList.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.cell_nine_tablet_standard));
    viewList.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.cell_ten_tablet_standard));
    viewList.add(rootView.findViewById(R.id.cell_eleven_tablet_standard));

    return rootView;
}

public void loadFragments() {
    int index = 7;
    index += (currentPageIndex - 1) * 12;
    for (int i = index; i < itemList.size() && i < index + 12; i++) {
        int currentViewId = viewList.get(i - index).getId();
        PrestoTabletCellFragment currentFragment = new PrestoTabletCellFragment();
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        PrestoItem item = itemList.get(i);

        String thumbnailUrl = item.getThumbnailUrl();
        String headline = item.getHeadline();
        String lastUpdated = item.getLastUpdated();
        String url = item.getUrl();

        data.putString("thumbnailUrl", thumbnailUrl);
        data.putString("headline", headline);
        data.putString("lastUpdated", lastUpdated);
        data.putString("url", url);

        currentFragment.setArguments(data);

        FragmentManager fm = MainActivity.supportManager;
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(currentViewId, currentFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
After further debugging, I produced the following output to give me a clue as to where the problem lies:

```
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427dd9f8 #2 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427e8e38} into view 2131361810
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427dd9f8 #2 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{4278d198} into view 2131361811
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427dd9f8 #2 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{42743328} into view 2131361812
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427dd9f8 #2 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427f1e38} into view 2131361813
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427dd9f8 #2 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427f1ef8} into view 2131361814
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427dd9f8 #2 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427f1fb8} into view 2131361815
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427dd9f8 #2 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427f2078} into view 2131361816
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427dd9f8 #2 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427f2298} into view 2131361817
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427dd9f8 #2 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427f2430} into view 2131361818
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427dd9f8 #2 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427f25c8} into view 2131361819
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427dd9f8 #2 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{4274c4b8} into view 2131361820
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427dd9f8 #2 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{42ae95f0} into view 2131361821
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427e3540 #3 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427de3f0} into view 2131361810
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427e3540 #3 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427f2e18} into view 2131361811
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427e3540 #3 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427f30e8} into view 2131361812
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427e3540 #3 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427f33b8} into view 2131361813
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427e3540 #3 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427f3710} into view 2131361814
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427e3540 #3 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427d35c0} into view 2131361815
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427e3540 #3 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427f3d80} into view 2131361816
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427e3540 #3 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427d4aa8} into view 2131361817
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427e3540 #3 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427f43f0} into view 2131361818
10-07 16:43:31.875  26180-26180/com.gannett.dolly.Titans D/snw﹕ fragment PrestoTabletStandardFragment{427e3540 #3 id=0x7f0a0011} loading cell PrestoTabletCellFragment{427d6e90} into view 2131361819
```

If you scroll through that to the right side, it appears the same view ids are being used for every fragment. Is this correct? I had assumed every unique instance of a fragment would have its own unique instances of the views within the layout (those are ids for FrameLayouts), these are being loaded into a list by onCreateView when the page is created. Is there another way I should go about this to ensure that the proper, unique identifiers are loaded for each unique page?

Comment: you are aware that by default `ViewPager` only loads the previous, current and next fragments correct?

Comment: Yes, however my TabletFragment class calls loadFragments on all fragments in the ViewPager. Debug logging indicated the method is being called on the proper fragment, but nothing is happening. It's very possible I'm missing something obvious in how this interaction works though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be in the loadFragments method of the StandardTablet class. I was using:

```
FragmentManager fm = MainActivity.supportManager;
```

when I **should** have been using:

```
FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
```

This resulted in the MainActivity fragment manager using the first matching view id it found, which was the one in the first StandardFragment. Changing to the childFragmentManager allows it to find the proper view for each unique fragment, and everything works smoothly after that.